# SQL Azure Database. Login with non-secure connection string

Tags: sql-server, azure, connection-string, auditing

I have an SQL Azure database and have the auditing enabled on it. According to the portal , Auditing requires use of Security Enabled Connection Strings and consequently have set the Security Enabled Access parameter on the DB portal to “Required” so that no apps with non-secure connection strings get to my DB.

When I try to get connected from SSMS using non secure connection string server name like `MyAzureServer.database.windows.net` I get an error message saying only connections with secure connection string are allowed which is what I expected

However my .NET application using the non-secure connection string like below works fine and no errors. I could also see that there is a record in audit logs that login was success

```
Server=tcp:MyDBServer.database.windows.net,1433;
Database=DemoDB;
User ID=Srisail@MyDBServer;
Password=password123%;
Encrypt=True;
TrustServerCertificate=False;
Connection Timeout=30;
```

My question is how my .NET app using the non-secure connection string able to login to my Azure SQL Server although I had forced my server to accept only connections with secure connection string.

Also I’m not sure if I fully understand secure and non-secure connection strings, except you include the text secure in your server name like `MyDBServer.secure.database.windows.net`. I would like to understand more on this.

Like always any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am glad to inform you that last week we have improved the behavior of DB “Required” mode, which eliminates the need to use the secure connection string to use auditing or data masking.

This means that SSMS or .NET app attempts to connect the database using the standard connection string will works fine with no errors, after you set the Security Enabled Access parameter on the DB portal to “Required”,

Could you please try get connected from SSMS using the standard connection string after setting the Security Enabled Access parameter on the DB portal to “Required?

Comment: Is this a quote from a blog (please add the reference to the article)? Or are you one of the developers at Azure (please introduce yourself then)?

Comment: Thank You @ron-matchoro. Nadav Helfman from Microsoft replied to my question on Azure support portal. [link]( http://disq.us/8n0ut3). Hope the documentation is updated soon.
If you are using TDS version 7.3 and below then the connection won’t go through if you are using non- secure connection string and the “Security Enabled Access” is set to TRUE on your Azure DB. SQL 2008 SSMS uses TDS 7.3 and so the error. My .NET app was using FW 4.5 which uses TDS 7.4 and so no error. Recompiled to FW 3.5 and I saw the error.

Comment: @ronmatchoro if security enabled access is set to "Required", is auditing still supposed to happen for applications not using the secure connection string?

Answer (score 15):

Just change

```
Server=tcp:MyDBServer.database.windows.net,1433;Database=DemoDB;User ID=Srisail@MyDBServer;Password=password123%;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=30;
```

To

```
Server=tcp:MyDBServer.database.secure.windows.net,1433;Database=DemoDB;User ID=Srisail@MyDBServer;Password=password123%;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=30;
```

Comment: My question was how my .NET app using the non-secure connection string able to login to my Azure SQL Server although I had forced my server to accept only connections with secure connection string.

Answer (score 1):

Your connection string includes `Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False` so  qualifies as a secure connection.
The connection between client and server will be SSL encrypted and the certificate will be validated.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ff394108.aspx#encryption

Comment: Thanx @alex-s. As per MSDN Traditional connection string format: <server name>.database.windows.net and Security-enabled connection string: <server name>.database.secure.windows.net. I wanted to know what exactly happens when we send Secure vs non secure connection string.